# Get one of the two types of a Typescript union type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this union type:

```
export interface IUserInfosLogin {
  usernameOrEmail: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface IUserInfosRegister {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirm: string;
}

export type TUserInfos = IUserInfosLogin | IUserInfosRegister;
```

And I would like a `const [userInfos, setUserInfos] = useState<TUserInfos>{}` to take just one of these types, but when I try to access `userInfos` only `password` is available.

Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a [Discriminating Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as otherwise, for TypeScript it can be one or another, so it only recognises what they share, in your case `password`. Notice that `type` added on both:

```
export interface IUserInfosLogin {
  type:"login";
  usernameOrEmail: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface IUserInfosRegister {
  type:"register"
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirm: string;
}

export type TUserInfos = IUserInfosLogin | IUserInfosRegister;
```

And you would need a type checking, in order to have one or another:

```
if(userInfo.type === "login"{
  // you can access IUserInfosLogin properties here
}else{
 // you can access IUserInfosRegister properties here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem and I understand now what my problem was